# How can I set a function to an event listener

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this function displaySelectedUser, so I want to Set displaySelectedUser as a change event listener for the `<select></select>` UI element using only the DOM Selector API.

this is the code that I have tried out:

```html
<body>
<div class="select">
      <select class="select-text">
        <option disabled selected>Select User</option>
         <option>user 1</option>
         <option>user 2</option>
      </select>
</div>
<body>
<script>
   const displaySelectedUser = () => {
 //some code...
};
    document.querySelector('select').change = displaySelectedUser;   
  };
</script>
```

Comment: `.onchange = displaySelectedUser;` or `.addEventListener('change', displaySelectedUser);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using the HTML5 Selector API.

```
 document.querySelector(".select").addEventListener("change", displaySelectedUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an onChange event handler on the select element which calls that function directly.

```
<body>
<div class="select" onChange="displaySelectedUser()">
      <select class="select-text">
        <option disabled selected>Select User</option>
         <option>user 1</option>
         <option>user 2</option>
      </select>
</div>
<body>
<script>
   const displaySelectedUser = () => {
 //some code...
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tim has mentioned you can simply add **onchange** instead of **change** in your code and it woks.

```html
<body>
<div class="select">
      <select class="select-text">
        <option disabled selected>Select User</option>
         <option>user 1</option>
         <option>user 2</option>
      </select>
</div>
<body>
<script>
   const displaySelectedUser = () => {
 //some code...
     alert('calling')
};
      const powerupTheUI = () => {
    document.querySelector('select').onchange = displaySelectedUser;   
  };
  
  powerupTheUI();
</script>
```